# How can I make Ubuntu 20.04 work with a surface laptop's keyboard?

Tags: keyboard, 20.04

I installed Ubuntu 20.04 on my surface laptop, and my keyboard doesn't work. I have searched for solutions to this problem in tutorials, and nothing can help me.

Comment: Which version of Surface Laptop is it?